# I can't seem to install Team Viewer 9; keeps downloading 8

Tags: macos, teamviewer

I downloaded TeamViewer to my iMac ( v 10.5.8 ); inadvertently loaded 8 instead of 9. When I download what I think is version 9, it keeps showing up as version 8? I uninstalled 8, did everything else I can think of?

Comment: Well unless you are downloading `http://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_8x/TeamViewer.dmg` instead of `http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewer.dmg` what you are downloading actually is version 9.  Have you remove version 8 from the system before trying to run version 9?

Comment: [Version 9](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_9x/TeamViewer.dmg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some more work to figure out exactly where the disconnect is.

If you have an icon in the dock, command click it, and then right click/control click and "Get Info" to see what the version number is.

If you know where the executable is on your hard drive, do the same, and also verify that it's what your dock icon is pointing to (if applicable).

When you download TeamViewer, you will mount the DMG, and then open the Install TeamViewer package file. After Installer is open, go to File -> Show Files. At the bottom of the list should be something like `TeamViewer9.otf`. (Note, this is just what I found -- you normally won't be able to identify versions with Installer this way.)

Remove the TeamViewer.app package from the Applications folder, and install the installer package. Be looking at the Applications folder while this happens. You will see the .app get installed into the applications folder, and when it is done, use Get Info to see the version that is installed.

If all of this works, but the app's "About TeamViewer" shows the wrong version, then you will know that the disconnect has to do with a problem with TeamViewer itself.

Comment: Also note that there does not appear to be great feature parity between the Windows and Mac versions, so if you are only observing this because you're missing a feature that you think you're supposed to have, chances are you're just wrong.

Answer (score -2):

The links on Teamviewer's own site seem to be pointing to the old version (8).

Download 9 from here instead: http://download.cnet.com/TeamViewer/3000-7240_4-10869706.html

Comment: CNET download link should not be trusted.  People should use http://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_9x/TeamViewer.dmg instead.